# variable might not have been initialized and constructor cannot be applied to given types errors in java fraction project

Tags: java

I am trying to fix the method to reduce a fraction for a fraction project using java. This is current code:

```
private static void reduce() {
    Fraction thisFraction = new Fraction(thisFraction.n, thisFraction.d);
    thisFraction.getNumerator();
    thisFraction.getDenominator();
    int factor = thisFraction.gcd(thisFraction.n,thisFraction.d);
    thisFraction.n/=factor;
    thisFraction.d/=factor;
}
```

The line starting with Fraction thisFraction gives me an error saying variable thisFraction may not have been initialized. I tried taking out the parameters in this line, but that gives me an error saying constructor Fraction in class Fraction cannot be applied to given types. I also need to make sure that I don't have any non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context errors since the reduce method is static. I'm not sure what I should do to fix this method. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: You cannot use "thisFraction" on the line you're creating the object `thisFraction` what do you intend the numerator and denominator to be?

Comment: Concur with Matt. You can't put the cart before the cart.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you use

> Fraction thisFraction = new Fraction(thisFraction.n, thisFraction.d);

in a method with the signature:

> private static void reduce()

That signature implies the operation is based on the *whole class*. Any Fraction should have this specific value. So to know what to use for your arguments you need to decide. If this is a static method then make the signature:

```
private static void reduce(Fraction thisFraction);
```

And remove the

> Fraction thisFraction = new Fraction(thisFraction.n, thisFraction.d);

The difference between static and non-static is.

Say we have a fraction.

```
Fraction a = new Fraction(2, 4);
```

Now, we want to reduce the fraction. There are one of two ways. With a static method,

```
static Fraction reduce(Fraction f){
    int factor = gcd(f.numerator, f.denominator);
    return new Fraction( f.numerator/factor, f.denominator/factor );
}
```

Alternatively we can use an instance method.

```
Fraction reduce(){
    //uses this.numerator and this.factor
    int factor = gcd(numerator, denominator)
    return new Fraction(numerator/factor, denominator/factor);
}
```

Notice the big difference, if "reduce" is static it should work on a provided fraction. You cannot "reduce" the general class, but you can reduce a known fraction.

In our example.

```
Fraction r = a.reduce(); //non-static version.
Fraction r2 = Fraction.reduce(a); //static version.
```

Both `r` and `r2` should be 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the object on the sameline as you are initializing it

```
Fraction thisFraction = new Fraction(thisFraction.n, thisFraction.d);
```

This will not work, rather

```
Fraction thisFraction = new Fraction(10, 15);
```

This will initiate the "thisFraction" variable and you can use it after that.